# Android App - Radio Buttons, TextView, and Layout Options

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button

I'm creating my first android app. It seems fairly simple. But I'm a total noob with Java and Android (I'm more familiar with C, C++ and the like). I'm sorry if this is the dumbest question ever. Anyway, I followed the steps on the android dev website.

The app is supposed to have the person enter their Name and click on 1st, 2nd, or 3rd shift radio buttons and when they click on Downtime Button, they'll be brought to another page (activity) that displays their name and the shift they picked and then displays another textbox and a time input.

So far, I got the MainActivity.java done like this:

```
package com.cyapps.downtime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.cyapps.downtime.MESSAGE";

    public void clickedButton1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void clickedButton2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClamperDTActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void clickedButton3(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherDTActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the activity_main.xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="@string/radio_button1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/radio_button2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/radio_button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button_send1"
        android:onClick="clickedButton1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button_send2"
        android:onClick="clickedButton2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send3"
        android:onClick="clickedButton3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I now have another activity that shows up when you finish entering in your name and clicking on a shift. This page is supposed to show your name and the shift number and have a textbox to write some other stuff in it and a time input and a submit button. I know how to do buttons and I see the time input on the interface of Eclipse. But I don't understand how to make the radio buttons be able to be "submitted" and shown on the page and how to edit the activity to show certain stuff. I'm confused.

This is how the WinderDTActivity.java looks like:

```
package com.cyapps.downtime;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WinderDTActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

And this is what the activity_winder_dt.xml looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you so much in advance if you help me. You have no idea how grateful I'll be. I've been trying really hard to understand this, but I'm thoroughly confused on how to get xml and java working together. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already sending the contents of the text box to the second activity just fine, right? Then you only need to do two more things to send the radio button state through as well:

1. Implement onClick handlers for the radio buttons. You've already done that for the submit buttons, so I assume you've figured out onClick stuff. In the radio button onClick, set a variable in MainActivity.
2. Package the variable the radio flags set into the intent's extra data, like so:

   ```
   intent.putExtra("radioButtonState", radioButtonState);
   ```

   You can read the result back in your second activity using the appropriate `intent.getxxxxExtra()` function (`getIntExtra` if you saved an int, for example).

Comment: Ohhh, okay. I've implemented onClick handlers. And on my second activity, I put `        intent.getStringExtra( MainActivity.radioButtonState );`
under my other intent which gets the operator's name.
But now when I try to run it, it doesn't even show the operator's name like it used to. :( I'm sorry if this is annoying and ridiculous.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation for Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Note that although there are many predefined extra strings, like `EXTRA_TITLE`, the interface for `Intent.putExtra(String, String)` will take any string. It should have the package name in front of it, but any string you define is ok.

Comment: More specifically, in anywhere add  a couple of String constants: `public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "com.example.myApplication.name";` and `public static final String EXTRA_RADIO_STATE = "com.example.myApplication.radioState";`. Later, when creating the Intent: `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name); intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RADIO_STATE, radioButtonState);`. In activity 2's onCreate: `String name = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME); int radioButtonState = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RADIO_STATE);`

Comment: Hi again, I still am a little off on this code.. Do you mind answering a couple more questions for me? If not, I can make a new question.. But it seems like you really really know what you're doing! And I really appreciate your help. But I wasn't sure if this thing is getting a little cramped up. May I email you or anything?

Comment: It is getting cramped, but stackoverflow doesn't seem to have private messages (goes against the philosophy of the website), and I don't like posting my email address publicly. So cramped it is! To tell the truth, I really don't know what I'm doing -- I only started Android development a month or so ago and I made mistakes in my own code that I only found looking at the API documentation because of your question! So I need to go fix my code now too.

Comment: But I'll give you this advice: the three best places you can look for help are the Android API docs, Google (which usually leads you back here to stackoverflow.com, this place is very good), and the Replica Island source code, [here](http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Freplica%2Freplicaisland%253Fstate%253Dclosed). It's a game, so it won't be doing everything it seems you want to do, but it was where I got started with starting new activities and intents and all that.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for your help though! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

you have to not written `Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1)` in `onCreate` methid

this is the reason your are not getting button click event

similarly write code for button2 and button3